# need cube plot for 2 factors factorial design in R

Tags: r, factorial, anova

Is there are any R package that can produce cube plots for 2 factors? I want something similar to the first plot at the end of this page 
http://www.processma.com/resource/factorial_plots.htm

It is possible to obtain such plots in Minitab.

In the package FrF2 there is the command cubeplot but only for 3 factors.

Of course I can use 2 identical factors, but want images with nice squares(instead of cubes).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cubePlot` from `FrF2` package. It produces a cube plot for the combined effect of three factors. Here an example :

```
data(BM93.e3.data)  #from BsMD
iMdat <- BM93.e3.data[1:16,2:10]  #only original experiment
colnames(iMdat) <- c("MoldTemp","Moisture","HoldPress","CavityThick","BoostPress",
                     "CycleTime","GateSize","ScrewSpeed", "y")
iM.lm <- lm(y ~ (.)^2, data = iMdat)
cubePlot(iM.lm, "MoldTemp", "HoldPress", "BoostPress")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a package that generates a cube plot for more than three factors?  So, for four factors this would be two three factor cube plots with the fourth factor being each of the two cubes (one low the other high).

Comment: late to the party but just run two cubes, one for each level of the fourth variable